# Java regex to match "t" except when it's "[t" or "t]"

Tags: java, regex

I'm using replaceAll() on a string to replace any letter with "[two letters]". So xxxaxxx to xxx[ab]xxx. I don't want the ones that have already been replaced to be done again (turns to xxx[a[cb]]xxx)...

An easy way to do this would be to exclude any letters that are proceded by a "[" or followed by "]". What's the correct Regex to use?

replaceAll(foofoofoo, "[ab]");

Comment: For future reference, editing your question bumps it to the front page. There's no need to add an answer to bump it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s.replaceAll("(?<!\\[)t(?!\\])", "[ab]");
```

These are respectively a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead, two examples os zero-width assertions. More info can be found in [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

One thing the above does it excludes [t]. I suspect that's what you want but if not, you'll need to modify it slightly.

Comment: Are you missing the final closing parenthesis there?

Comment: yeah... need a ")" after the final closing bracket. Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind and lookahead, like this:

```
(?<!\[)t(?!=\])
```